# how to get direct value from a list that contain an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, get

how to get direct value from a list that contain an array ?

hey guys ,
i want to directly get a certain value from a list that contain an array

```
 List<int[]> myList = new List<int[]>();
 myList.Add( new int[2] { 10, 11 } );
```

its clear for me to get this using foreach loop like

```
foreach ( int[] p in mylist)
      console.write(p[0]);
```

i do want to retrive this single data using expression like list[0] for list of integers

thanks..

Comment: `int v = myList[0][0]; `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is very unclear, but if you know the array index within the array, you can use:

```
int value = myList[listIndex][arrayIndex];
```

Effectively this is just doing:

```
int[] array = myList[listIndex];
int value = array[arrayIndex];
```

Comment: Indeed - I care far more about the question being good. (In this case the question is unclear *as well*, but...)

Answer (score 1):

im not entirely sure what you mean . . .

it would look like a 2d array: myList[position of array in list][position of item in selected array].  this is because a list is generic container and the overloaded bracket operator will return the specific type (which in this case is an array), that then enables you to use the bracket again to refer to the items contained in the array.

the snipplet you wrote actually only iterates the first item foreach array in your list (was this on purpose)?

in essence, you kind of need 2 pieces of information unless you only want the first item in each list (position 0) in which case you would create a new container class, implement the IList interface and overload the bracket operator like this:

```
    public int this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return myList[index][0];
        }
        set
        {
            myList[index][0] = value;
        }
    }
```